# iOS - how can I export a mix audio composition to a file of smallest file size?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio, avmutablecomposition

I use `AVAudioRecorder` to record sound, the out put file format is `.caf`. And then I add a background sound (which is also in `.caf` format) onto the audio that I recorded, with  `AVMutableComposition`. It works perfectly when I try to play it.

Now I want to export it and save it with the following code. However, the filesize of the exported file increase a lot. (for instance, the audio that I record is 16045byte, the background sound is 50400byte, and the exported file is 246472byte which is larger than the sum of the two file by times.)

```
AVAssetExportSession *export = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
export.audioMix = audioMix;
export.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
NSString *exportURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/export.m4a", DOCUMENTS_FOLDER];
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportURL];
export.outputURL = outputURL;

[export exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    int exportStatus = export.status;

    switch (exportStatus) {
       // check the status and do the handling
    }
}];
```

}

So, can some one teach me to how I can make the output audio file smaller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about fileTypes here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009539:

```
NSString *const AVFileTypeAIFC;
NSString *const AVFileTypeAIFF;
NSString *const AVFileTypeAMR;
NSString *const AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat;
NSString *const AVFileTypeAppleM4V;
NSString *const AVFileTypeMPEG4;
NSString *const AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
NSString *const AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
NSString *const AVFileTypeWAVE
```

AIFC might be interesting for you since it's compressed.

You will have to update also presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A to presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz, thanks for the reference. I have tried to change the export.outputFileType to AVFileTypeAIFC, and the export file export.m4a to export.aifc. However, it doesn't work. Here is the error message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid output file type'. Do I miss anything?

Comment: Can you paste an output of supportedFileTypes ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetExportSession/supportedFileTypes

Comment: Ah you also have AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A when you initialize the class - I updated my answer.

Comment: Here is the output of supportedFileTypes: 2013-09-12 21:56:20.648 VoiceRecorder[4831:c07] Supported Output: (
    "com.apple.m4a-audio"
)...Seems that it only support AVFileTypeAppleM4V.

Comment: oh, so what preset name should I use?

Comment: I used exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset: to find out the compatible presets for my composition. Here is the result: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality,
    AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A,
    AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
    AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality,
    AVAssetExportPreset640x480. So, which one should I use?

Comment: oh, it runs with no error prompt. However, the filesize of the output file is 0 in AVFileTypeAIFC. When I change it to AVFileTypeAppleM4A, it has 200kB. hm..why is that??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37266/discussion-between-grzegorz-krukowski-and-newbie)